# Take average of rows with the same value with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv formatted as following:

```
Year  Number
2001  5
2001  10
2003  15
```

My goal is to take a user input (year) and take the average of all the numbers that share the same year using python's pandas.

For example, If I chose the year "2001" I should get 7.5.

Comment: `df[df["Year"].eq(2001)].mean()`?

Comment: Or rather `df.groupby('Year').mean()`

Answer (score 0):

I would take the input data, convert it to "int", then filter your dataframe accordingly and take the mean value from ['Number'] column.

So it would look like this:

```
#Preparing the data
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Year']=pd.Series([2001,2001,2003])
df['Number']=pd.Series([5,10,15])

#Take input year from user
x=input(prompt='Please enter a year number: ')

#Filter your df by the input from customer , then select 'Number' column and calculate the mean
df[df['Year']==int(x)]['Number'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m using a standard dataframe of mine.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Service': np.arange(8),
           'Ticket': np.random.rand(8),
           'Year' : np.random.randint(2010,2013,8),
           'Var_1': np.random.rand(8), # values column
           'Var_1_View': 'temp temp temp temp temp temp temp temp'.split(), # header of values of column
           'Var_2': np.arange(8), 
           'Var_2_View': 'pres pres pres pres pres pres pres pres'.split(),
           'Var_3': np.arange(8) * 2,
           'Var_3_View': 'shift shift shift shift shift shift shift shift'.split(),
           'D': np.arange(8) * 5,
           'Mess_3': np.random.rand(8),
           'Mess_3_View': 'id id id id id id id id'.split(),
           'E': np.arange(8)})

df_extract=df.groupby('Year').mean()

df_extract.loc[int(input('Please insert Year...'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = df[df['Year'].eq('Year of interest')].mean()

print(f"{a.to_string()}")
```

If you use this method, it will print out the answer but also give you an error. You can ignore this with:

```
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

Obviously not a permanent fix.